# Is there any way to solve the initial bluetooth connection lag?

Tags: keyboard, 20.04, mouse, bluetooth, dell

Whenever I've not touched my Bluetooth mouse or keyboard for a while, it takes up to a second for them to wake up, causing me to miss the first mouse movements or keystrokes, which is pretty annoying when working.
I've already tried this solution, but it doesn't seem to make a difference: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/539122/bluetooth-mouse-lag

I'm using a Microsoft Designer Bluetooth Desktop Keyboard and Mouse set on Ubuntu 20.04 on a Dell XPS 13 9300.

Comment: I've got the exactly same problem with my Dell XPS 13 9300, Ubuntu 20.04, and bluetooth mouse MX Master from Logitech. There is a big lag when I'm not using the mouse for 4-5sec and start moving it. The cursor move only after 0.5 sec, very annoying... Let me know if you find anything, I doesn't.